# Maximam of finite sums

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, functional-analysis, complex-analysis, banach-spaces

It is not so difficult to prove the following estimate:
Let $\Gamma \subset \mathbb{C}$ be a finite set.

$$
\sum_{z \in \Gamma} |z|
\leq \pi \max_{\Gamma^* \subset \Gamma}\Big|\sum_{z \in \Gamma^*} z\Big|.
$$

Can we generalize this inequality to the general Banach spaces?
More precisely, let $X$ be a Banach space, and $\Gamma \subset X$ be a finite set. Does the following estimate hold?

$$
\sum_{x \in \Gamma} \|x\|_X
\leq C \max_{\Gamma^* \subset \Gamma}\Big\|\sum_{x \in \Gamma^*} x\Big\|_X,
$$
where $C$ does not depend on $\Gamma$.

Comment: Is $X$ a finite or infinite dimension?

Comment: probably holds in a Hilbert space but not sure in a Banach space

Comment: @Conrad I think so as well

Answer (score 1):

**Partial answer**: if $X$ is infinite dimension, let $\left\{e_n: n\in \mathbb N\right\}$ infinite orthonormal family of $X$ and let $\Gamma_n = \left\{e_k: k\le n\right\}$ then it is clear that if $C$ exists, $C^2\ge n$.